# How to catch Zoom event with GWT and Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, gwt, dom-events

I've seen there is much conversation about how to get the current zoom factor in the browser, but I haven't found out why this snippet works in Firefox, and not in Chrome.

```
public class MyComposite extends Composite
{
  public MyComposite()
  {
    HTMLPanel panel = new HTMLPanel("<applet>...</applet>");
    panel.addDomHandler(new MouseWheelHandler()
    {
        @Override
        public void onMouseWheel(MouseWheelEvent event)
        {
            event.stopPropagation();
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    }, MouseWheelEvent.getType());
    initWidget(panel);
  }
}
```

In both browsers, when I scroll inside the div containing the applet, the scroll is not propagated to the parent (which is fine). And when I scroll outside of the div, the window is scrolled (which is also fine).

But when I do *Ctrl+MouseWheel*, in Firefox the zoom event is caught by the handler and not propagated whereas in Chrome the handler seems not to be called, and the event is then propagated. I would like to stop the propagation in Chrome as well.

Is there a bug in Chrome or am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: does Ctrl+MouseWheel execute the same functionality as Ctrl+[+/-]? (I'm assuming this is Windows behavior...)

Comment: Indeed, it is the default shortcut for zooming.

Ctrl+[+/-] should not be caught by the handler (and it is not).

Comment: Is it not caught by  `Window.addResizeHandler()`?

Comment: It seems caught, but then I have another problem : `stopPropagation` and `preventDefault` can not be called from a ResizeEvent (parameter from onResize method inside ResizeHandler). Besides, I am not sure I want to prevent that from the complete window. I would rather only stop the propagation when the mouse cursor is inside the concerned div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Late heads-up : this seems to be a bug in Chrome. I filed [a report](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Iteration%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified&groupby=&sort=&id=111059) a couple of years ago but it seems not to be a priority for them. If you stumble upon this post and you want that "feature" too, please leave a message on that report, maybe it will speed up the things...