# Chrome - Javascript prevent default Ctrl + MouseWheel behavior

Tags: google-chrome, default, dom-events, mousewheel, ctrl

I'm trying to prevent the default <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>MouseWheel</kbd> zoom behavior in Chrome with JavaScript, for the other browsers I use `preventDefault()` and `stopPropagation()` in the callback function for mouse-wheel event and works perfect because the other browser always trigger a mouse-wheel event but Chrome does not.

Reading the question [How to catch Zoom event with GWT and Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8885299/how-to-catch-zoom-event-with-gwt-and-chrome)
I found that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>MouseWheel</kbd> can be caught as a resize event but after zooming the page so I can't prevent the behavior with this one.

Is there other event created before <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>MouseWheel</kbd> in Chrome or is a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's impossible to intercept or block the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + scrollwheel (zoom) event in Chrome.

This issue is being tracked at https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=111059. Star the issue to get notified of (progress) updates.

Answer (score 13):

Trying to prevent zoom on window/document/body does not really work but wrapping the contents of the body with a div and preventing zoom on this works fine.

```js
document.getElementById('root').addEventListener('wheel', event => {
  if (event.ctrlKey) {
    event.preventDefault()
  }
}, true)
```

```css
#root {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: silver;
}
```

```html
<div id="root">no zoom allowed</div>
```

Comment: Thumbs up! Works for me, Chrome 73.0.3683.86, Linux.

Comment: fyi, in brave/chrome if you happen to be using document.writeln() inside the callback, it does something, probably changes the focus, dunno, but the first such event gets trapped and the rest bypass the target, so it seems to be broken, but it's not. just spent 10 minutes figuring that out

Comment: Note that onWheel preventDefault is broken in React. Handling the wheel event with a ref and addEventListener or onwheel works fine, but the property onWheel directly on the div does not work. https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/19654

Answer (score 4):

As of Chrome 76, the `wheel` event on `window` can be cancelled, but **only if you register a passive event listener**. From other answers and examples it seems like you can also cancel the event if it's on a DOM element such as a root `<div>`.

```js
window.addEventListener('wheel', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
}, { passive: false });
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  background: #AAA;
}
```

```html
<p>
  Inside of this page, you cannot zoom with the mouse wheel.
</p>
```

Comment: I'm confused by this answer. It works `only if you register a passive event listener` -- but your example registers an event explicitly with `passive: false`, and the documentation says having a passive event listener disables `preventDefault()`.

Answer (score 3):

'wheel' event and preventDefault are working now. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/wheel).

Answer (score 1):

Found this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyLN5/) on chromium bug tracker forum, seems now the issue has been fixed.
Chromium now sends ctrl+wheel events to webkit first before using them for zooming. Rather than prevent scrolling for these events in `EventHandler::handleWheel`
`event.preventDefault()` should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

### **For React JS**

In my project, I added a ref for my component and then added event listener to the ref and set passive to false to disable the default Zoom in and out.

```
useEffect(() => {
const element = boxRef.current;
if (element) {
  element.addEventListener("wheel", handleWheel, {
    capture: true,
    passive: false,
  });
}

return () => {
  if (element) {
    element.removeEventListener("wheel", handleWheel);
  }
};
}, []);
```

My html is as follows:

```
<Box
    ref={boxRef}
    sx={{
      position: "relative",
      height: "100%",
      transform: `scale(${zoomValue / 100})`,
    }}
  ></Box>
```

My handleWheel funcion is:

```
const handleWheel = (event) => {
if (event.ctrlKey) {
  event.preventDefault();
  //control key is pressed
  if (event.deltaY > 0) {
    //scrolled down
    console.log("Scroll Down");
  } else {
    //scrolled up
    console.log("Scrolled Up");
  }
}
};
```

This works fine for me and I'm able to add my custom Zoom in and Zoom out.

Answer (score -1):

as a improving of @Vl4dimyr 's answer

```
document.getElementById('root').addEventListener('wheel', event => {
  if (event.ctrlKey) {
    event.preventDefault()
  }
}, true)
```

---

```
#root {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  /*-------------------important part----------------------*/
  /*bottom: 0;*/
  min-height:100vh; /*extendible cover for document*/
  /*-------------------------------------------------------*/
  left: 0;
  background: silver;
}
```

---

```
<div id="root">no zoom allowed</div>
```